# formatting the entered time in a html input time type

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make the user in input of type time **can only enter the value of minutes xx:00 or xx:30.**

In the code below I tried to round the minutes up or down.

But I am not satisfied, because when I click on input I am not able to immediately enter a two-digit hour, e.g. 12 or 23, because it reads it to me as 12 - 01 later 02, 23 - 02 later 03 (check sb yourself)

anyone else have an idea how to do this?

```js
const timeInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.test1, input.test2');

const roundFunc = e => {
    let x = e.target.value.split(':');
    if (x[1] > 00 && x[1] < 15) {
        x[1] = "00";
    } else if (x[1] > 44 && x[1] < 60) {
        x[0] = x[0] < 10 ? "0" + (parseInt(x[0]) + 1) : parseInt(x[0]) + 1;
        x[1] = "00";
    }
    else {
        x[1] = "30";
    }
    e.target.value = x.join(':');
}

timeInputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('input', roundFunc);
});
```

```html
<input class="test1" type="time">
<input class="test2" type="time">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`step`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#step) (in seconds):

```html
<input type="time" step="1800">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I notice that if the minute is "00" you will set the time to "30". You need to change this condition:

```
if (x[1] > 00 && x[1] < 15) {
```

to this:

```
if (x[1] >= 00 && x[1] < 15) {
```

Also, as written the rounding is asymmetric; the time is more likely to be 30 than 00, since 45 and 15 both go to 30. You might want to set one of these to 00.

I hear that Format="HH:mm" should work for 24 hour mode, but I haven't tried this myself.